# Can't query $.post returned data

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
 $.post( url, JSON_POST,
    function( data ) {
      var content = $( data );
          var content = $( data ).find( '#json' );
        console.log(data);
           console.log(content);
      }
    );
```

The result of the first console.log is

```
<div id="json">{"status":1,"message":"Reply submitted successfully."}</div> 
<div id="test">sdfsafdsfds</div>
```

But for some reason the second log returns an empty array. I am trying to query the html inside the data variable but the result is always the null set.

I would really appreciate helping me with this. I went through the $.post manual but nothing is mentioned about the this problem.

P.S I am using JQUERY 1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` looks for **descendants** of the selected elements. In your case, both elements have no descendants, not to mention any with ID `json`.

Instead, you are looking for a specific element of the selected ones. In this case, you should [`filter` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the current elements:

```
var content = $(data).filter('#json');
```

Comment: sweet thanks. I guess I am gonna buy me a JQuery book for the little things that I am missing.

Comment: @SenouciOTHMANE: You're welcome :) My advice is to read the documentation carefully and get familiar with the DOM terminology.

Comment: @omnosis: Wrong.  He isn't using XML; there is nothing wrong with multiple roots.

Comment: yes he does. he calls a `$.post` which is an ajax request, and the `data` is the response.

Comment: @omnosis: And who says that the response is XML? Your solution is correct as well and another way to solve it, which is fine, but the OP never states that he is working with XML. (Btw if you don't mention SLaks with `@SLaks`, he will not be notified of your comment).

Comment: @FelixKling Maybe I missed something, but this response is at least xhtml which is part of xml. Definetly i cant see what content type was set, but i guess some kind of xhtml or xml.

Comment: @omnosis: It could as well be just HTML, which is not XHTML and therefore not XML. It's fine to transfer snippets instead of complete documents. Or maybe the content-type is just `text`...

Answer (score 1):

do you use a container element in the XML?
maybe this cause the problem.

You **MUST** use root element in the xml to get the correct parse. So your XML response should look like:

```
<root>
    <div id="json">{"status":1,"message":"Reply submitted successfully."}</div> 
    <div id="test">sdfsafdsfds</div>
</root>
```

the `<root>` element can be anything you like, for example: `<foo>` or `<div>`

---

Yes this is your problem.

Try this in javascript console:

```
var asd = '<div id="json">{"status":1,"message":"Reply submitted successfully."}</div><div id="test">sdfsafdsfds</div>'

console.log($(asd).find("#json")) > []
console.log($("<root>"+asd+"</root>").find("#json")) > [<div id="json">{"status":1,"message":"Reply submitted successfully."}</div>]
```